# Computer program for the conjugacy problem of $GL_n(\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, integer-programming, computer-algebra-systems, computational-algebra

In "Solution of the conjugacy problem in certain arithmetic groups" Grunewald provided an algorithm for solving the conjugacy problem of $GL_n(\mathbb{Z})$.

My question is:

Is there some computer program realizing this algorithm? Where to find it?